# Why can I only index into a HashMap sometimes?

Tags: rust

I have a Graph object whose edges refer to the nodes by index into the list of vertices. The nodes themselves are an unrelated ID type, so I include an index map. When constructing the edges in `new()`, I can easily index into the local variable: `node_index_map[&src]` but when I create a helper function to get the index to build new edges later, I get the error:

```rs
error[E0608]: cannot index into a value of type `HashMap<V, usize>`
```

Why does this happen?

Minimal code ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3ea8873134cbec810fd7073a1e277ec2)):

```rs
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::hash::Hash;

pub struct Edge<E> {
    id: E,
    src: usize,
    dst: usize,
    wt: u64
}

pub struct Graph<V, E> {
    nodes: Vec<V>,
    node_index_map: HashMap<V, usize>,
    edges: Vec<Edge<E>>,
}

pub fn build_graph<V, E>(v: V, e: E) -> Graph<V, E>
where V: Copy + Eq + Hash, E: Eq + Hash {
    let mut node_index_map = HashMap::new();
    let nodes = vec![v];
    node_index_map.insert(v, 0);
    let edges = vec![Edge { id: e, src: node_index_map[&v], dst: 0, wt: 1}];
    Graph {
        nodes,
        node_index_map,
        edges,
    }
}

impl<V, E> Graph<V, E> {
    pub fn node_index(&self, node: V) -> usize {
        self.node_index_map[&node]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aaaand it's because I'm missing the trait bounds on the impl.

```rs
impl<V, E> Graph<V, E>
where V: Eq + Hash
{
    pub fn node_index(&self, node: V) -> usize {
        self.node_index_map[&node]
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd expect to see `impl Index<V>` here if you want true indexing.